# AVI to MP4 - ffmpeg conversion

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg

I'm running a debian 7.5 machine with ffmpeg-2.2 installed following [these instructions](http://wiki.hznteam.fr/trac-bubble/wiki/FfmpegInstallation)

### Issue

I'm trying to display a mp4 video inside my browser. The original file has an AVI container format. I can successfully convert it to mp4 and the targetfile is readable (video + sound) with the totem movie player. So I thought everything would be OK displaying the bellow page

### HTML5 web page

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <title>Webcam</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
  <source src="/path/to/output.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<h3>Your browser does not support the video tag</h3>
</video>
</body></html>
```

### Input probe

```
$ ffprobe -show_streams input.avi

  Duration: 00:08:22.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1943 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 720x540 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1870 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 25 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 25 tbc
```

### Convert

$ ffmpeg -y -fflags +genpts -i input.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy ouput.mp4

### Html browser

Opening the above html file plays sound but no video is displayed.

When I use other .mp4 files, videos succesfully  displayed so I'm sure I face a conversion issue.

Not : I've tryed a lot of other ffmpeg options but without success.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're certainly right but as my goal is to use ffmpeg with the python ffmpegwrapper 0.1-dev I need to find out general ffmgeg settings that fits with my main needs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your command was [stream copying](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-muxing) MPEG-4 Part 2 video into MP4 container, but this format is probably not playable by the browser. You should use H.264 video instead for MP4 container:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 <... more options ...> -c:a libfaac \
-movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

`-movflags +faststart` will allow the video to begin playback before the file is completely downloaded by the viewer.

Note that you can specify multiple alternative media resources for compatibility:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
  <source src="/path/to/output.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="/path/to/output.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source src="/path/to/output.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  ...
</video>
```

Also see:

- [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide)
- [FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AACEncodingGuide)
- [FFmpeg and VPx (webm) Encoding Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/vpxEncodingGuide)

Comment: Hello Igor, that what I found out with minor differences to streamline the video display on the client side : for .webm encoding :  ffmpeg -y -i input.avi -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis -minrate 512K -maxrate 512K -b:v 512K -f webm output.webm and for .mp4 encoding : ffmpeg -y -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k -f mp4 output.mp4. For the latter I use an MP audio codec instead of the AAC one

Comment: And if insterested I've written a memo that summerizes informations I found over internet about this topic. It's hosted on my server : http://wiki.hznteam.fr/trac-bubble/wiki/FfmpegInstallation

Comment: @EmmanuelBrunet I added some additional information to this answer. You shouldn't use `-minrate`. See the VPx link in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice LordNeckbeard, could you explain why the lin-rate shouldn't be set ? honestly I've not really understand how it works ...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the WebM format instead of an MP4. If you look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) it seems that WebM is a good choice for compatibility.

And in fact I made a similar test by own

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <title>Play a file</title>
</head>
<body>
<video width="640" height="480" controls>
  <source src="vid/output.webm" type="video/webm">
<h3>Your browser does not support the video tag</h3>
</video>

<video width="640" height="480" controls>
  <source src="vid/output.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<h3>Your browser does not support the video tag</h3>
</video>

</body></html>
```

And I used a video converted by:

- ffmpeg -i F:\Videos\bbb_1sec.ts ./vid/output.mp4
  and
- ffmpeg -i F:\Videos\bbb_1sec.ts ./vid/output.webm

the MP4 video doesn't work under Firefox 29... but the WebM version is OK

In another hand the conversion will take more time due to the transcoding to VP8/vorbis.
But your input video stream that you copied (transmux) into the mp4 file my be out-of the spec(**Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658)**)