# HTML5 video not playing in Chrome and IE11 (exhaustive test case provided)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, video, html5-video

I am trying to include a screencast taken with [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) in a HTML5 webpage. It works on Firefox and Opera (latest versions tested), but doesn't work on IE11, nor Chrome, at least on my machine.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello world</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
    <source src="helloworld.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="helloworld.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="helloworld.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>

</body>

</html>
```

This HTML listing validates against the standard. [Here is the full, published test case](http://bit.ly/1p3dBBv).

You are welcome to inspect the videos by downloading them from the server in order to assess if they were encoded correctly; however, this is how I encoded them:

```
ffmpeg -i helloworld.avi helloworld.mp4
ffmpeg -i helloworld.avi helloworld.webm
ffmpeg -i helloworld.avi helloworld.ogv
```

If you need the original `helloworld.avi`, [here it is](http://bit.ly/1scSUZI). I got my `ffmpeg` from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-20140613-git-1c5aa64-win64-static.7z).

I believe the server responds with the appropriate `Content-Type`, as you are welcome to verify yourself.

What am I doing wrong?

I *kindly* ask you not to give me generic answers, if possible, but to discuss the actual test case: I am trying to provide you with everything is needed, and you can ask for more information.

Comment: I get `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE` ("An error of some description occurred while decoding the media resource, after the resource was established to be usable") in Chrome. Maybe this will help - [AVI to MP4 - ffmpeg conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23827512/avi-to-mp4-ffmpeg-conversion/23845993)

Comment: Thanks. How were you able to retrieve that debug information? Would you please be so kind to download and inspect the MP4 file and tell me if you notice something awfully wrong. I have checked it and the video codec is actually H264

Comment: If something is wrong with media element, always check `networkState`, `readyState` and `error.code` (if `error` is not `null`) attributes. Unfortunately, don't have time to check the video right now, I will try to do it asap.

Answer (score 2):

Your html is fine as it is. The resolution of the video (471x390) does not work well with most codecs. ffmpeg does error about this if using `-strict`.  I re-encoded the video and it works for me now and I cropped of a pixel to get a dividable-by-two version (the crop filter):

```
ffmpeg -i helloworld.avi  -filter:v "crop=470:390:0:0" -c:v libvpx -crf 6 -b:v 3M -qmin 2 -qmax 42 -quality best -cpu-used 0  helloworld.webm

ffmpeg -i helloworld.avi -filter:v "crop=470:390:0:0" -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -strict -2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 12 -subq 9 helloworld.mp4
```

The other parameters I took from a script I regularly use for encoding videos for html.  Especially iOS turned out to be quit picky about encoding options.

Comment: This makes the video play correctly on all desktop browsers I have. My researches on the topic didn't reveal anything about this resolution issue, as people are probably always using standard resolutions. You already did a lot for me, but have you got any ideas on how to make it work on Android web browser (as it is not working).

Comment: Can you upload your new encoded videos so I can take a look at them?  For me the webm and mp4 version both work on android (tested on 4.4).

Comment: Here are the new videos encoded with your options: http://bit.ly/1nKvtSd This test case plays well in any desktop browser, but the "Internet" built-in application in my Galaxy S4 mini shows a black rectangle. The same happens in Chrome (on that device). Strangely, it plays in Firefox for mobile.

Answer (score -1):

You can use other browse. or try this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello world</title>
</head>

<body>

<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
    <source src="helloworld.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="helloworld.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="helloworld.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>

</body>

</html>
```